# Резервное копирование процедур/функций при изменении их в MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

У нас есть База Данных, в которой много процедур и функций, есть ли возможность настроить задание или триггер, что при изменении старая версия процедуры куда-нибудь сохранялась?

Comment: для этого обычно используют системы контроля версий (SVN, TFS и тп)

Comment: На одном из предыдущих мест работы применялось отслеживание изменений в схеме БД по общим триггерам и в табличку с логами сохранялись дата и время изменения, логин пользователя, который внес изменения, и предыдущий код процедуры. Соответственно потом при разборе полетов можно было выяснить кто, когда и какие изменения внес в базу. На мой взгляд такой алгоритм дополняет хранение данных в системе контроля версий из-за человеческого фактора (кто-то внес быстрый фикс на бою, кто-то забыл внести изменения в СКВ и т.д.). Выбор зависит от целей сохранения истории.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужны [DDL триггеры](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-triggers?view=sql-server-ver15). Примерный алгоритм:

1. Создать таблицу для логов с датой внесения изменения, пользователем, внесшим изменения, и самими изменениями. В изменения можно записывать текущую версию процедуры/функции и/или результат выполнения функции [EVENTDATA](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eventdata-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).
2. Создать триггеры по примерам [Database Level DDL Triggers for Views, Procedures and Functions](https://www.sqlshack.com/database-level-ddl-triggers-for-views-procedures-and-functions/) или [DDL Triggers in SQL Server with Examples](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/ddl-triggers-in-sql-server/).   Тут же можно добавить откат изменений в случае, если они не соответствуют заданным условиям.